# Is there a way to initialize a custom setting in a test class?

Tags: unit-test, customsetting

My test class inserts test quote line items which sets off a trigger, that calls a Util class to pull a query of qli fields, 5 of which have their names stored in custom settings (I'm not 100% why this is necessary, this was Quote/Opportunity line item syncing that a consultant created for us previously). The debug log clearly shows this Util class pulling the names from the custom settings properly in all cases Except for my test class. ( I tried adding a quote line item in the tool, and running other existing test classes). The result of the incomplete query is a 'SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field' error for the missing fields, since they are referred later in the trigger.

When I turn on seeAllData on my class, the trigger queries the fields from the custom settings. However, I don't want to do this and so I'm wondering if there's another way to 'make visible' the custom settings to my test class? Otherwise, I am unable to insert any test QuoteLineItems or OpportunityLineItems without getting the error.

Please let me know if this question makes any sense.

Here's some of the code snippets:

part of the Util class pulling the field names from the Custom Setting (QuoteLineSyncField__c),

```
 public class QuoteSyncUtil {

public static boolean isRunningTest = false;  

private static Map<String, String> quoteFieldMap = new Map<String, String>();
private static Map<String, String> quoteLineFieldMap = new Map<String, String>();

static {
public static String getQuoteFieldsString() {    
    String fields = '';
    for (String field : getQuoteFields()) {
        fields += ', ' + field;
    }
    return fields; 
}
    Map<String, QuoteLineSyncField__c> quoteLineFields = QuoteLineSyncField__c.getAll();
    system.debug('KENNY '+quoteLineFields);

    for (String quoteLineField : quoteLineFields.keySet()) {
        QuoteLineSyncField__c quoteLineSyncField = QuoteLineSyncField__c.getInstance(quoteLineField);
        //FIXME - uppercase value cause NPE
        quoteLineFieldMap.put(quoteLineSyncField.Name, quoteLineSyncField.OppLineSyncField__c);
        system.debug('KENNY '+QuoteLineSyncField__c.getInstance(quoteLineField));
        //quoteLineFieldMap.put(quoteLineField, quoteLineSyncField.OppLineSyncField__c);            

    if(quotelinefield == 'Product_Type__c'){
        System.debug('********* ' + quoteLineField);
        System.debug('^^^^^^^^^ ' + quotelineSyncField.OppLineSyncField__c);
        }
    }
}

public static Set<String> getQuoteLineFields() {
    system.debug('KENNY '+quoteLineFieldMap.keyset());
    return quoteLineFieldMap.keySet();
}
```

part of the trigger that builds the query (qliQuery is the list of field names returned by the Util class):

```
List<String> oppLineFields = QuoteSyncUtil.getOppLineFields();

// pricebook entry ids in trigger
Set<Id> pbEntryIds = new Set<Id>();

// a Set of Pricebook2 Ids represented in Trigger.new
Set<Id> setPricebookId = new Set<Id>();

String oliFields = QuoteSyncUtil.getOppLineFieldsString();
String qliFields =  QuoteSyncUtil.getQuoteLineFieldsString();

String qliIds = '';
String quoteIdString = '';
for (QuoteLineItem qli : qlisInTrigger) {
    if (qliIds != '') qliIds += ', ';
    qliIds += '\'' + qli.Id + '\'';

    if (quoteIdString != '') quoteIdString += ', ';
    quoteIdString += '\'' + qli.QuoteId + '\'';

    pbEntryIds.add(qli.PricebookEntryId);
}

String qliQuery = 'SELECT Id, ' +
                    'QuoteId, ' +
                     'PricebookEntryId, ' +
                     'UnitPrice, ' +
                     'Quantity, ' +
                     'Discount, ' +
                     'ServiceDate, ' +
                     'SortOrder, ' + 
                     'PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, ' +
                     'PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Type__c, ' +
                     'PricebookEntry.Product2.Approval_Required__c, ' + 
                     'PricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id, ' +
                     'ListPrice, ' +
                     'Discount_off_List__c ' +
                     qliFields + 
                     ' FROM QuoteLineItem where QuoteId in (' + quoteIdString + ')';

System.debug(qliQuery);
```

Finally, my test class errors out wherever I try insert a QuoteLineItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can instantiate a custom setting like any other custom object. In this case you would create as many instances of `QuoteLineSyncField__c` as needed. After populating them with the data you need, `insert` them like a normal object as part of your test setup.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my question was short sighted. I initialized the custom settings in my test class but now the Util class still returns an empty set for QuoteSyncLineField__c.getAll()